# Mapping moya result with moya_modelMapper

Tags: iphone, swift, rx-swift, moya

I have the following function in my webservice class:

```
 func loadTransport() -> Observable<[TransportResponse]> {
        let nonce = "\(Date().timeIntervalSince1970)"
        let csaKey = try! config.apikey()
        let csaSecret = try! config.apiSecret()

        let csaSignature = crypto.generateSignature(nonce: nonce, url: "http://*****/v1/nmbs", body: "", secret: csaSecret)
        print("SIGNATURE = \(csaSignature)")

        let endpointClosure = { (target: TransportService) -> Endpoint<TransportService> in
            let url = target.baseURL.appendingPathComponent(target.path).absoluteString
            let endpoint = Endpoint<TransportService>(URL: url, sampleResponseClosure: {.networkResponse(200, target.sampleData)}, method: target.method, parameters: target.parameters)
            return endpoint.adding(newHttpHeaderFields: ["CSA-KEY": csaKey,"CSA-NONCE": nonce,"CSA-SIGNATURE": csaSignature])
        }



        let provider = RxMoyaProvider<TransportService>(endpointClosure: endpointClosure, plugins: [NetworkLoggerPlugin(verbose: true)])
        return provider
            .request(TransportService.nmbs)
            .filterSuccessfulStatusCodes()
            .mapArray(type: TransportResponse.self)
    }
```

And in my TransportViewModel I have this init method:

```
 init(webService: Webservice) {
        self.webService = webService

        title.value = String.localizedString(key: "transport_title")



        transportResponse = active.asObservable()
            .filter { $0 }
            .flatMap {  _  in
                return webService.loadTransport()
            }
            .map { response in
                return [TransportData(items: response)]
        }    
    }
```

The problem is it comes in my `flatMap` method but it never comes inside the `map` below the `flatMap`.

When I add a subscribe part to my webservice function like this:

```
 let provider = RxMoyaProvider<TransportService>(endpointClosure: endpointClosure, plugins: [NetworkLoggerPlugin(verbose: true)])
    provider
        .request(TransportService.nmbs)
        .filterSuccessfulStatusCodes()
        .mapArray(type: TransportResponse.self)
        .subscribe { event in
            switch event {
            case .next(let response):
                print(response)
            case .error(let error):
                print(error)
            default: break
            }
    }.addDisposableTo(disposeBag)
```

I see that my response is correctly printed. 
Can anybody help me with this?

Comment: Please post a response JSON and `TransportResponse` model.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue is that your provider gets deallocated as soon as `loadTransport()` method is finished.

You are using the old version of Moya. Until this [pull request](https://github.com/Moya/Moya/pull/905) `RxMoyaProvider` was captured weakly, so the whole chain would not emit any event at all (next/error/completed).

To fix that, covert provider to a class-scoped variable:

```
class Webservice {
    var provider: RxMoyaProvider<TransportService>?
}
```

And use it like this:

```
self.provider = RxMoyaProvider<TransportService>(endpointClosure: endpointClosure, plugins: [NetworkLoggerPlugin(verbose: true)])
return self.provider!
    .request(TransportService.nmbs)
    .filterSuccessfulStatusCodes()
    .mapArray(type: TransportResponse.self)
```